# Enable mongo PHP extension in Microsoft Azure Websites

Tags: php, mongodb, azure, web

I'm trying to load `php_mongo.dll` extension in Azure Websites.
 I tried this guide http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/using-custom-php-extensions , but it doesn't work.

I looked at the `phpinfo()` but the extension does not get loaded. At one point, I managed to do it, but I have no idea how I did it. Now it doesn't work anymore.

Is there a working guide to how to activate custom php extensions on azure websites? Or any idea how I can do this?
 Thank you!

PS: I'm using `PHP_EXTENSIONS  : bin\php_mongo.dll` in App Settings, PHP version 5.5, where `php_mongo.dll` is 1.6.2-5.5-VC11-X86-NTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer: use double backslash.
`bin\\php_mongo.dll`