# Azure PHP Mongodb extension

Tags: php, mongodb, azure

I cannot manage to setup the database on Azure Web App. I followed the instructions exactly from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/ (section 4). The error I get on my web app is:

> Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in D:\home\site\wwwroot\index.php on line 42

I downloaded the DLL of MongoDB named php_mongo-1.6.8-5.4-vc9-nts.dll, and renamed it to php_mongo.dll, moved it to a directory bin, and updated the web app settings accordingly (PHP_EXTENSIONS=bin/php_mongo.dll).

I tried the following solution, with no success:
[Enable mongo PHP extension in Microsoft Azure Websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28464509/enable-mongo-php-extension-in-microsoft-azure-websites)

Comment: can you write a `phpinfo()` and see if the dll is loaded ? Also what version are you running ?

Answer (score 1):

I tested the function for configuring PHP extensions via App Settings which is mentioned in [official article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime) at section **Configure via App Setting**.

The following images are my configuration:

Test project directory:
[image]

App Settings:
[image]

And check PHP runtime in `phpinfo`:
[image]

It worked fine for me by following official article.

Please check whether you had missed any steps, or had completely upload the extension file, and check whether the extension file is match your PHP version. You also can use FTP or kudu console to check your extension file.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was pretty stupid. I hope Microsoft will fix it someday.

They said the relative path is the root directory, but its not, its the deployment directory.

So on the App Settings I had to specify
PHP_EXTENSIONS=D:\home\bin\php_mongo.dll